# Could I switch out the shell on my GBA SP (AGS-101) with the intact one from my other console (AGS-001)?

Tags: hardware, game-boy-advance

I have a backlit console (AGS-101) with a broken shell. Console still works. I have a frontlit console (AGS-001) with an intact shell. Can I put the AGS-001's shell on my AGS-101?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [a few reports on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Gameboy/comments/qpmigo/can_you_swap_an_ags101_sp_with_the_shell_of_an/), the cases should be perfectly compatible to swap.

Just note that you'll need to swap the entire GBA, not just the screens. The motherboard->screen connection changes between revisions.